# Script CMD de inicio de sesión para crear una variable no se ejecuta

Tags: batch

He creado un script básico para que cuando una persona inicie sesión en el equipo cree una variable con su nombre completo de AD.

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in ('net user %username% /domain ^| find /i "nombre completo"') do set DATA=%%B
```

El caso es que si lo pongo por GPO de inicio de sesión lo ejecuta, pero no crea la variable. Si cojo el código y lo ejecuto con sesión iniciada en la consola, eliminando uno de los % funciona sin problemas.

si lo ejecuto como `.bat` tampoco funciona.

Ya cambié *nombre completo* por *full name*, creado la variable antes, ejecutar en inicio de equipo.

No se si me dejo alguna cosa.

Comment: Prueba cambiando `SET` por `SETX` de  la siguiente forma: `setx DATA %%B`.  A diferencia de `set`, `setx` lo hace permanente. Nota; Es sin el signo `=`

Comment: Vale, funciona con setx, pero lo que no sabia es que hay que reiniciar ya que las variables se guardan en memoria al inicio y no se pueden ver las creadas nuevas desde la consola cmd.

Por otro lado si algún programa llega a usar esa variable, por mi experiencia si la recoge sin necesidad de reiniciar. bginfo (que muestra datos en el escritorio) lo hace (si se ejecuta después de crear la variable). Gracias por el aporte